# How to assign string values and store it in hashmap then retrieve it separately?

Tags: java, string, split, hashmap

I am new to the Comp Sci. I have this string that contains

```
    String assign = "1111222233334444";
```

and I have a List of strings which user inputted such as

```
    List<String> num = new ArrayList<>(); 
    **ex** num = "'a 1111', 'b 2222', '[newline] 3333', 'c 4444'"
```

How do I make it so that

```
    a will contains 1111 values and b will contains 2222 values and so on.
```

In the end, when user put in something like

```
    "1111222233334444" and it will return like 
     OUTPUT
     ab
     c
```

My approach to the solution is that you split the List num and assign it to some string character.
Some help please.

Comment: unfortunately, you are asking too many things at once. you have just given a list of requirements. this is not the proper way to use Stack Overflow! read [ask] in the Help Center

Comment: What is `num = "'a 1111', 'b 2222', '[newline] 3333', 'c 4444'"` supposed to represent? Is that string predefined, or does it come from user and you need to process it? If so how? What should be result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into String's method split() on how to separate the letter from the numbers in each of those strings.  Once split, you'll be given an array that contains all the pieces minus the delimiter you decide (the space character in your case).  Once you have that, you can grab the first index to use as your hashmap's key, and the second index to use as your hashmap's value.

```
hashMap.put(splitStr[0], splitStr[1]);
```

You'll want this to be in a loop so it can be done for each string in your original list

Comment: thanks! how do i retrieve the hashmap key in a return statement?

Comment: Maps aren't meant to look for and return keys, the keys are meant to be known or calculatable for the singular purpose of looking up values.  If you want to work with the keys in a map, you will need to call map's keySet() method, which gives you ALL keys in a Set object, then you can look through them in a loop and pick one you want.

Comment: You can ask the map if it contains a value under a particular key using the containsKey() method

Comment: If you want to lookup the letters by using the numbers, then you should put the number as the key and the text as the value. however, Guava also has a [BiMap class](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) which allows you to lookup key by value.